# Клик по элементу div вызывает действие этого div

Tags: jquery

Есть блок в котором метки с крестиками (метки появляются динамически - ajax). На крестик висит событие. И на блок тоже висит событие. Проблема в том, что при нажатии на крестик, также срабатывает событие блока. Как быть?

```js
jQuery('#sample_orders').click(function(e) {
  freehand();
});

function freehand() {
  console.log('freehand');
}

jQuery('#sample_orders').on('click', '.delete-order', function() {
  console.log('delete');
});
```

```css
#sample_orders {
  border: 1px solid gray;
}

.delete-hover:hover {
  color: #F44336;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="sample_orders" class="text-center myborder pointer">
  <h4>Выбрно</h4>
  <span class="label label-success" data-o_id="58">
  <span>F2</span> &nbsp;
  <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove delete-hover delete-order"></span>
  </span>
</div>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Попробуй

```
jQuery('#sample_orders').on('click', '.delete-order', function(e) {
    e.stopPropagation();
    console.log('delete');
});
```